# How do I write a 2D array of Characters in Swift?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I'm trying to translate this Java code into **Swift**, but I'm having no luck so far.

```
public final int rows = 6;
public final int columns = 7;
public char board[][] = new char[rows][columns];
```

Basically, I want to create a 2D array of (Character)s with the rows and columns variable giving the dimensions (size) of the 2D array.

Comment: FYI: I think the downvotes are because the question is interesting, but we need some Swift then *something*, an error, a failure point, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows: Int = 6
var columns: Int = 7
var boardColumns: [Character] = [Character](count: rows, repeatedValue: "c")
var board: [[Character]] = [[Character]](count: columns, repeatedValue: boardColumns)
```

In swift you have to initialize a non optional variable at declaration. You could make this an optional by doing like so:

```
var rows: Int = 6
var columns: Int = 7
var boardColumns: [Character?] = [Character?](count: rows, repeatedValue: nil)
var board: [[Character?]] = [[Character?]](count: columns, repeatedValue: boardColumns)
```

to make the values in the array optional, or you could declare the whole thing as an optional, but you have to declare it as something before you can use it.

```
var board: [[Character]]?
```

If you want to append values on to it, you can to initialize it like so

```
var board: [[Character]] = [[]]
```

Comment: I tried adding the second piece of code in my project and I'm getting this error: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: I wrote this from memory, but it is close. The second piece of code I am like 99% sure of though. I'll edit it.

Comment: Sorry, I never use characters. Apparently I am not soposed to use Char >.<

Answer (score 0):

`var rows: Int = 6
 var columns: Int = 7`

`let data: [[Character]] = [[Character]](count: rows, repeatedValue: [Character](count: columns, repeatedValue: " "))`

It will initialise all the `Characters` with empty values